# Android: Browse and upload a PDF or word file in application from the device

Tags: android, pdf, ms-word

I am creating an android mobile application in which user can upload his/her resume and which can be then sent to the server.

Resume can be in pdf form or word form.

How to browse for the pdf and word files, which type should be given to browse these files? like for images we have image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function:

```
 private void getDocument()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("application/msword,application/pdf");
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            // Only the system receives the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, so no need to test.
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_DOC);
        }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int req, int result, Intent data)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(req, result, data);
if (result == RESULT_OK)
        {
        Uri fileuri = data.getData();
                    docFilePath = getFileNameByUri(this, fileuri);
}
}

// get file path

    private String getFileNameByUri(Context context, Uri uri)
    {
        String filepath = "";//default fileName
        //Uri filePathUri = uri;
        File file;
        if (uri.getScheme().toString().compareTo("content") == 0)
        {
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION }, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            String mImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
            cursor.close();
            filepath = mImagePath;

        }
        else
            if (uri.getScheme().compareTo("file") == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    file = new File(new URI(uri.toString()));
                    if (file.exists())
                        filepath = file.getAbsolutePath();

                }
                catch (URISyntaxException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                filepath = uri.getPath();
            }
        return filepath;
    }
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I am trying this code but not able to get the document when starting activityforResult from fragment, can you help ?

Comment: @Shailesh have you got the onActivityResult call back in your call fragment ?

Comment: yes I am getting call back in fragment but not able select the PDF file

Comment: getFileNameByUri() returning null if i use intent.setType("application/pdf"); instead of intent.setType("application/msword,application/pdf");