# Getting null value while upload pdf file from device memory

Tags: android, pdf

In my application i want to upload pdf file from device. So for that i have followed bellow link

[[Android: Browse and upload a PDF or word file in application from the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182417/android-browse-and-upload-a-pdf-or-word-file-in-application-from-the-device][1])

By using this code, after select pdf file getting null value. This **getFileNameByUri** method return **null** vlaue. I dont know, what is the issue hare. So please suggest me. 
Thanks In Advance...

This the code i am using...

```
private void getDocument()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("application/pdf");
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            // Only the system receives the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, so no need to test.
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
```

And this is the onactivity result

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int req, int result, Intent data)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(req, result, data);
if (result == RESULT_OK)
        {
        Uri fileuri = data.getData();
        docFilePath = getFileNameByUri(this, fileuri);
}
}
```

And this is the method for file path..

```
private String getFileNameByUri(Context context, Uri uri)
    {
        String filepath = "";//default fileName
        //Uri filePathUri = uri;
        File file;
        if (uri.getScheme().toString().compareTo("content") == 0)
        {
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION }, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            String mImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
            cursor.close();
            filepath = mImagePath;

        }
        else
            if (uri.getScheme().compareTo("file") == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    file = new File(new URI(uri.toString()));
                    if (file.exists())
                        filepath = file.getAbsolutePath();

                }
                catch (URISyntaxException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                filepath = uri.getPath();
            }
        return filepath;
    }
```

here this method **getFileNameByUri** returns null value..

Comment: Try to figure out your problem using `Log` . I do check this code and it return me the name of file and full path.

Comment: you need to upload file and file name then it will not be null Have you converted your file in to URI....

Comment: yes, i have checked getting this column_index values is 0 here....int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); @sagar

Comment: yes i have converted, please check the url i have pasted above @amitsharma

Comment: Yes that is 0. but you are expecting over there ? Zero does not mean that it is null.

Comment: you are uploading to your server m i right .. where is your File upload code .or your onActivity Result.. Share here your code to find your exact issue..

Comment: Please post the problematic code here.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the file path from the MediaProvider, DownloadsProvider, and ExternalStorageProvider, while falling back to the unofficial ContentProvider method you mention.

```
/**
 * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
 * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
 * other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri The Uri to query.
 * @author paulburke
 */
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri The Uri to query.
 * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}


/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

These are taken from [Paul Burke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/377260/paul-burke)'s answer